# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I am trying to get a JSON response from a get request. However, I am getting the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`. I know the rails route works because I do get the response loaded successfully in the Console.

The Ajax Response is supposed to start when the checkbox changes and is checked.

Why am I getting this error from the `$.parseJSON`?

**Rails Controller**

```
def providers
   @providers = User.order("last_name ASC, first_name ASC, middle_name ASC").where("provider_flag = ? and inactive_flag = ? and del_flag = ?", true, false, false).select("id, CONCAT(IFNULL(last_name,''), ', ', IFNULL(first_name,''), IFNULL(middle_name,'')) AS full_name");

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => { :providers =>  @providers.to_json}, :status => :ok }
        # format.json { render :json => @providers.to_json }
    end
end
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#provider_chk').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%= providers_schedule_index_path %>',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    authenticity_token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('loaded successfully.');
                    var providers = $.parseJSON(data.responseText)['providers'];
                    providers_count = $(providers).size();
                    console.log(providers);
                    console.log(providers_count);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log("An error has occurred!")    
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#providers_results').empty();
        }
    });
```

**JSON Response**

```
providers: "[{"id":2,"full_name":"Test, User"}]"
```

Comment: What is your Json? did you test the Json with [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com). I see your code but what actual response did you get back could you post that?  you can get that with a console.log(data);

Comment: Yes, the JSON is valid. Tested at JSON lint

Comment: Could you posted it, I see the def for providers

Comment: Thanks will look at it in context now : thanks

Comment: You are double encoding your JSON, which is not necessary. This *shouldn't* be the problem, but you should still remove `to_json`.

Comment: I actually just noticed this as well and have removed it

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response should look more like this:

```
providers: [{"id":2,"full_name":"Test, User"}]
```

The outermost quotations marks aren't needed.

If you really need the outer quote marks, you need to escape the inner ones.

Comment: I have never had any problems using `.to_json` with Rails. How would I change either the Javascript or Rails Controller?

Answer (score 0):

In $.ajax({}), add the property "async:false". parseJSON hasn't gotten that JSON yet - it's immediately trying to operate on undefined ("u") and throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `to_json` since you are already telling rails to return `json`

`format.json { render :json => { :providers =>  @providers }, :status => :ok }`